# Woodbury Matrix Inversion

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra

I am trying to invert a matrix using Woodbury identity. The inversion using Cholesky decomposition has the following pseudo-code:

> **For** $t=1,2,...$
>
> $(1)\;\; \text{Read}\;x_t\in\mathbb{R}^n$
>
> $(2)\;\;D_{t-1}=diag(|\theta_t^1|,...,|\theta_t^n|)$
>
> $(3)\;\;A_t=A_t+x_tx_t'$
>
> $(4)\;\;A_{t}^{-1}=\sqrt{D_{{t-1}}}\left(a\mathbf{I}+\sqrt{D_{{t-1}}}A_t\sqrt{D_{{t-1}}}\right)^{-1}\sqrt{D_{{t-1}}}$
>
> $(5)\;\;\text{Read}\;y_t\in\mathbb{R}$
>
> $(6)\;\;b=b+y_tx_t$
>
> $(7)\;\;\theta_t=A_{t}^{-1}b$
>
> **End For**

The well known application of Sherman-Morrison on Recursive Least Squares is as follows:

$$A_t^{-1}=(aI+x_tx_t')^{-1}=A_{t-1}^{-1} - \frac{(A_{t-1}^{-1}x_t)(A_{t-1}^{-1}x_t)'}{1+x_t'A_{t-1}^{-1}x_t}$$

where $A_0^{-1}=\frac{1}{a}I$ and we can set $A_t = A_{t-1}+\sum_{t=1}^Tx_tx_t'$, which will lead to time complexity of $O(n^2)$.

> The above technique is mentioned [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2690437). The two implementation in $\texttt{R}$ are as follows:
>
> ```
> X <-matrix(runif(1000),20,10)
> Y<-rnorm(20)
> a<- 0.1
>
> Cholsky<-function(X,Y,a){
>   X <- as.matrix(X)
>   Y <- as.matrix(Y)
>   T <- nrow(X)
>   N <- ncol(X)
>   aI<- diag(a,N)
>   bt<- matrix(0,ncol=1,nrow=N)
>   for (t in 1:T){
>     xt<-X[t,]
>     At <- aI + (xt %*% t(xt))
>     InvA<-chol2inv(chol(At))
>     bt <- bt + (Y[t] * xt)
>     theta<- InvA %*% bt
>   }
>   return(theta)
> }
> Cholsky(X,Y,a)
>
>
> Morrison<-function(X,Y,a){
>   X <- as.matrix(X)
>   Y <- as.matrix(Y)
>   T <- nrow(X)
>   N <- ncol(X)
>   At<-diag(1/a,N)
>   bt<- matrix(0,ncol=1,nrow=N)
>   for (t in 1:T){
>     xt<-X[t,]
>     At <- At + (xt %*% t(xt))
>     InvA <- At - ((t(xt%*%At)%*%(as.matrix(xt%*%At)))
>                     /as.numeric(xt%*%At%*%xt+1))
>     bt <- bt + (Y[t] * xt)
>     theta<- InvA %*% bt
>   }
>   return(theta)
> }
> Morrison(X,Y,a)
> ```
>
> They don't give the same result. So, perhaps I should not expect the implementations to be equivalent.

I was wondering if I could invert the following (for the above case) more efficiently:

$$A_t^{-1}=\left(D_{t-1}^{\frac{1}{2}}A_tD_{t-1}^{\frac{1}{2}}+aI\right)^{-1}$$

where $A_t=A_{t-1}+x_tx_t'$ and $A_0=\mathbf{0}$.

Essentially, I want to invert:

$$M_t=\left(a\mathbf{I}+\sqrt{D_{{t-1}}}x_tx_t'\sqrt{D_{{t-1}}}\right)$$

I say:

$$M_{t}^{-1}=M_{t-1}^{-1}-\frac{(M_{t-1}D_{t-1}^{\frac{1}{2}}x_t)(M_{t-1}D_{t-1}^{\frac{1}{2}}x_t)'}{1+x_t'D_{t-1}^{\frac{1}{2}}M_{t-1}D_{t-1}^{\frac{1}{2}}x_t}$$

where $D_0=diag(\mathbf{1}$). So, $M^{-1}_0=\frac{1}{a}I$

> RLS identity given above $(aI+u_tv_t)^{-1}$ uses $u=A_{t-1}^{-1}x_t,v_t=u_t'$,
>   I am using $u=M_{t-1}^{-1}D_{t-1}^{\frac{1}{2}}x_t,v_t=u_t'$

One may write the implementations in $\texttt{R}$ as follows:

```
X <-matrix(runif(1000),20,10)
Y<-rnorm(20)
a<- 0.1

#Cholesky implementation
X <- as.matrix(X)
Y <- as.matrix(Y)
T <- nrow(X)
N <- ncol(X)
bt<- matrix(0,ncol=1,nrow=N)
At<- diag(0,N)
I<- diag(a,N);Mt<-diag(1/a,N)
theta0<- rep(1,N)
for (t in 1:2){
  xt<-X[t,]
  Dt <- diag(sqrt(abs(as.numeric(theta0))))
  At <- At + (xt %*% t(xt))
  Mt <-  I + (Dt%*%At%*%Dt)
  InvA <- chol2inv(chol( Mt )) 
  AAt<- Dt %*%InvA%*% Dt
  bt <- bt + (Y[t] * xt)
  theta0 <- AAt %*% bt
  print(theta0)
}
```

Above is the correct implementation of the pseudo code. If I swap the following lines. I don't get the same answer.

```
Mt <-  Mt + (Dt%*%At%*%Dt)
InvA<- Mt - ((t(xt%*%Dt%*%Mt)%*%(as.matrix(xt%*%Dt%*%Mt)))
                   /as.numeric(xt%*%Dt%*%Mt%*%t(as.matrix(xt%*%Dt))+1))
```

Why is that?

Comment: so you want the inverse of the sum of two full rank matrices and expect Sherman Morrison to do it more efficiently?

Comment: how large is $T$?

Comment: We sequentially process $x_t,y_t$ and update $A_t$ at each itteration. $T=1,2,...$. In the above example $T=20$.

Comment: Use [this generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula#Generalization_(Woodbury_matrix_identity)) with $U=V^T=\sum_t D^{0.5}_{t-1}x_t$. I allows you to update the inverse of $aI$ by inverting a 20x20 matrix.

Comment: The thing is I don't know $T$ in advance. At each trial $t=1,2,...$ I need to invert $N\times N$ matrix. Where $N$ denotes the number of columns. I need to do it iteratively. Also, at each trial  $x_tx_t'$ (covariance matrix) is not positive definite, rather semi-positive definite.

Comment: The formula works iteratively too! I won't check your code, but feel free to post your steps as formulas.

Comment: don't you have $A_0 = aI$?

Comment: It seems to you failed to account for the dependence of $D_{t-1}$ on $t$, the index of the summation.  Perhaps these matrix factors should be moved inside the summation, where combining them with $x_t$ would seem not to increase the computational burden much.

Comment: Please avoid making numerous edits to your post. Each edit bumps the thread and this can be seen as "noisy" when done too often.

Comment: Thank you for telling me this, I was unaware. In future, I will do my best to avoid editing often.